# Detecting memory leak in cocos2dx project for WP8

Tags: memory, windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, cocos2d-x

I want to locate few memory leaks in my cocos2dx application for windows phone 8. `IDE` is Visual studio express 2012. I saw this link for [app profiling](http://bit.ly/19dsUBu). But as written on the page, "Only the Execution option is available for Direct3D apps". I am not able to figure out the option for memory profiling as `cocos2dx` uses directx in windows phone. How should I detect memory leak?

Comment: I also get this problem, my cocos2d-x app for wp8 run out of memory quickly...

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the application memory usage by following code.
Add the following code in App.xaml.cs

public partial class App : Application
 {

```
    private static Timer timer = null;
    public static void BeginRecording()
    {

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // start a timer to report memory conditions every 2 seconds
            timer = new Timer(state =>
            {
                // every 2 seconds do something 
                string report =
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " memory conditions: " +
                Environment.NewLine +
                "\tApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage: " +
                    getExactValue(DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage) + " MB" +
                    Environment.NewLine +
                "\tApplicationPeakMemoryUsage: " +
                    getExactValue(DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage) + " MB" +
                    Environment.NewLine +
                "\tApplicationMemoryUsageLimit: " +
                    getActualValue(DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit) + " MB" +
                    Environment.NewLine +
                "\tDeviceTotalMemory: " + getActualValue(DeviceStatus.DeviceTotalMemory) + " MB" + Environment.NewLine +
                "\tApplicationWorkingSetLimit: " +
                    getActualValue(Convert.ToInt64(DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit"))) + " MB" +
                    Environment.NewLine;

                // write to IsoStore or debug conolse
                Debug.WriteLine(report);
            },
            null,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }
    }
    public static decimal getExactValue(long stats)
    {
        return Math.Round(((decimal)(stats) / (decimal)(1048576.00)), 2);
    }

    public static int getActualValue(long stats)
    {
        return ((int)Math.Ceiling(getExactValue(stats)));
    }
```

now call the BeginRecording() function in application_launching.
this will give you the exact memory stats after every 2 seconds and you can identify the memory leaks.